# Change scheduler function code in kernel and recompile it

Tags: kernel, scheduler, freebsd

I want count number of scheduler function call in FreeBSD. 
FreeBSD use from [ULE scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ULE_scheduler) and I want to add a few lines in top of this function to logging it and then compile and install new kernel.

For example, I want to add these lines to scheduler function:

```
FILE *fp;
char* str = "string";
int x = 10;

fp=fopen("/tmp/mylog.log", "w");
if(fp == NULL)
    exit(-1);
fprintf(fp, "A new call of freebsd scheduler function  ");
fclose(fp);
```

Where is the scheduler function source code? And where is the exact place that I should copy this code? And what change are necessary for recompiling kernel?

Comment: Note that if you are programming the kernel, the standard C library cannot be used, although some functions have equivalents in kernel space, such as `printf(9)` and `malloc(9)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scheduler, located in sys/kern/sched_ule.c and rebuildable by doing "make buildkernel installkernel" in the top of the source tree, is part of the kernel.  That means the code above, which uses stdio, cannot work.  What could work would be to use existing facilities, such as Asynchronous Logging Queues (man 4 alq).

The easiest way of doing it would be to use DTrace, as that doesn't require rebuilding the kernel.